# Domino for maths

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to make my own version of the domino game below but I have no clue how to do it with tikz. EDIT: To be more precise, I don't know how to create the rectangles with the thick and thin borders and how to place the thin grey rectangles at the borders of the rectangles with the equations.
Any suggestions?
[image: domino for quadratic equations]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Seems like a simple table would be enough.

Comment: Is this of any use: https://github.com/loopspace/matching-puzzle ?

Comment: @AndrewStacey I can't try it because I don't know how to add the matchingpuzzle library to my system (ubuntu).

Comment: @SebGlav In a simple table, all borders would have the same thinkness, wouldn't they? Also, I wouldn't know how to add the thin grey rectangles at the borders.

Comment: @Georgios Download the file `tikzlibrarymatchingpuzzle.code.tex` and put it in the folder with your document.  The file `PowersJigsaw.tex` contains an example of its use.

Comment: At present it just has a hexagon layout so may not be suitable if you want something very like what you have above.  I'd do the above as a TikZ matrix.  Then the additional stuff would be very easy to add.

Comment: What is the purpose of these thin rectangles, anyway? And how are they supposed to be placed?

Comment: @SebGlav The thin rectangles show the student how to connect the dominoes (the thin rectangles of two dominoes have to be adjacent to each other). They are to be placed such that the dominoes form a closed loop when placed correctly (the student can therefore check by himself if he solved the domino correctly).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is one way to do it. I made a `pic` for the dominoes that takes three parameters: the texts (equations) and the position of the bottom thin rectangle. I also created parameters for the dimensions, this way the picture is easy to customize.

The code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pifont} % scissors: \ding{34}

% paramaters
\def\W{4}    % domino width
\def\H{5.5}  % domino height
\def\w{2.75} % (horizontal) thin rectangle width
\def\h{0.2}  % (horizontal) thin rectangle height
\def\tw{2.8} % text width

\tikzset
{%
    pics/domino/.style n args={3}{
    % USAGE:
    % #1 = top text
    % #2 = bottom text
    % #3 = bottom thin rectangle, 0 bottom / 1 left
    code={%
      \draw[line width=0.4mm] (0,0) rectangle (\W,\H);
      \draw (0,0.5*\H) -- (\W,0.5*\H);
      \node[text width=\tw cm,align=center] at (0.5*\W,0.75*\H) {#1};
      \node[text width=\tw cm,align=center] at (0.5*\W,0.25*\H) {#2};
      \draw (0,\H-\h) -| (\w,\H);
      \ifnum#3 = 0
        \draw (0,\h) -| (\w,0);
      \else
        \draw (\W-\h,0) -- (\W-\h,0.5*\H);
      \fi
    }},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[dashed] (0,0) -- (-1,0) node [left] {\ding{34}};
\pic at (0,0)     {domino={$x^2+4x+4=0$}{$(x+1)^2=0$}{0}};
\pic at (\W,0)    {domino={$x^2-x+6=0$}{$(x+2)^2=0$}{0}};
\pic at (2*\W,0)  {domino={$2x^2-6x-20=0$}{$(x+2)(x+5)=0$}{1}};
\pic at (3*\W,0)  {domino={$x^2+x-6=0$}{$3(x-1)(x+1)=0$}{0}};
\pic at (0,\H)    {domino={$x^2-x-6=0$}{$(x-2)(x+3)=0$}{1}};
\pic at (\W,\H)   {domino={$x^2+2x+1=0$}{$(x-3)(x+2)=0$}{0}};
\pic at (2*\W,\H) {domino={$x^2+4x-21=0$}{\sffamily Die Gleichung lässt sich nicth in Linearfaktoren zerlegen}{1}};
\pic at (3*\W,\H) {domino={$x^2+7x+10=0$}{$(x+7)(x-3)=0$}{0}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the dominoes:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I modified Juan Castaño's code so that the thin squares can be placed in any corner. Here's my modification with the complete domino:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pifont} % scissors: \ding{34}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

% paramaters
\def\lw{0.05} % line width
\def\sh{0.5*\lw} % half line width for shifting the thin rectangles
\def\W{4}    % domino width
\def\H{5.5}  % domino height
\def\w{0.5*\H-0.5*\lw} % (horizontal) thin rectangle width
\def\h{0.11}  % (horizontal) thin rectangle height
\def\tw{3.4} % text width

\tikzset
{%
    pics/domino/.style n args={4}{
    % USAGE:
    % #1 = top text
    % #2 = top thin rectangle, 0 left / 1 top left / 2 top right / 3 right
    % #3 = bottom text
    % #4 = bottom thin rectangle, 0 left / 1 bottom left / 2 bottom right / 3 right
    code={%
        \draw[line width=\lw cm] (0,0) rectangle (\W,\H);
        \draw (0,0.5*\H) -- (\W,0.5*\H); % center line
        \node[text width=\tw cm,align=center] at (0.5*\W,0.75*\H) {#1};
        \ifnum#2 = 0
        \draw[fill=gray!50] (\sh,\w+\sh) rectangle ++(\h,\w);
            \else\ifnum#2 = 1
            \draw[fill=gray!50] (\sh,\H-\h-\sh  ) rectangle ++(\w,\h);
                \else\ifnum#2 = 2
                \draw[fill=gray!50] (\W-\w+\sh,\H-\h-\sh) rectangle ++(\w,\h);
                    \else\ifnum#2 = 3
                    \draw[fill=gray!50] (\W-\h-\sh,\w+\sh) rectangle ++(\h,\w);
                    \fi
                \fi
            \fi
        \fi
    \node[text width=\tw cm,align=center] at (0.5*\W,0.25*\H) {#3};
    \ifnum#4 = 0
    \draw[fill=gray!50] (\sh,\sh) rectangle ++(\h,\w);
        \else\ifnum#4 = 1
        \draw[fill=gray!50] (\sh,\sh) rectangle ++(\w,\h);
            \else\ifnum#4 = 2
            \draw[fill=gray!50] (\W-\w+\sh,\sh) rectangle ++(\w,\h);
                \else\ifnum#4 = 3
                \draw[fill=gray!50] (\W-\h-\sh,+\sh) rectangle ++(\h,\w);
                \fi
            \fi
        \fi
    \fi
    }},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[dashed] (0,\H) -- (-1,\H) node [left] {\ding{34}};
\pic at (0,0)     {domino={$x^2-x-6=0$}{1}{$(x-2)(x+3)=0$}{3}};
\pic at (\W,0)    {domino={$x^2+2x+1=0$}{1}{$(x-3)(x+2)=0$}{1}};
\pic at (2*\W,0)  {domino={$x^2+4x-21=0$}{1}{\sffamily Die Gleichung lässt sich nicht in Linear\-faktoren zerlegen}{3}};
\pic at (3*\W,0)  {domino={$x^2+7x+10=0$}{1}{$(x+7)(x-3)=0$}{1}};

\pic at (0,-\H)    {domino={$x^2+4x+4=0$}{1}{$(x+1)^2=0$}{1}};
\pic at (\W,-\H)   {domino={$x^2-x+6=0$}{1}{$(x+2)^2=0$}{1}};
\pic at (2*\W,-\H) {domino={$2x^2-6x-20=0$}{1}{$(x+2)(x+5)=0$}{3}};
\pic at (3*\W,-\H) {domino={$x^2+x-6=0$}{1}{$3(x-1)(x+1)=0$}{1}};

\pic at (0,-2*\H)   {domino={$3x^2-3=0$}{1}{$(x-2)(x-3)=0$}{3}};
\pic at (\W,-2*\H)  {domino={$x^2-16=0$}{2}{$2(x+2)(x-5)=0$}{3}};
\pic at (2*\W,-2*\H)    {domino={$x^2-7x-18=0$}{2}{$(x-4)(x+4)=0$}{0}};
\pic at (3*\W,-2*\H)    {domino={$x^2-9x+18=0$}{2}{$(x-9)(x+2)=0$}{2}};

\pic at (0,-3*\H)   {domino={$x^2+\frac{3}{2}x+\frac{1}{2}=0$}{1}{$(x-3)(x-6)=0$}{0}};

\pic at (\W,-3*\H)  {domino={$x^2-5x+6=0$}{1}{$\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right(x+1)=0$}{3}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

That's what it looks like:

[image: complete_domino]